# Use a bluetooth headset JUST as a microphone?

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth, headphones

This is hopefully a pretty simple question. Is it possible to configure a bluetooth headset to act as only a microhphone? I am using OSX Mountain Lion. I would assume the process would be something like:

1. Pair the headset with OSX
2. Set audio input to be the device instead of line in
3. Set audio output to be the normal audio output, and not the bluetooth headset

If there are any known issues or headsets I should stay away from, I would appreciate a heads up as well. We have a new HTPC, a mac mini connected to our TV via HDMI for video/audio, and we were hoping to install Rosetta Stone for the family to use in the living room. Wireless is a must for the microphone!

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to configure a bluetooth headset only as a microphone, but Rosetta Stone would refuse to recognize that microphone. a USB or an analog microphone is a must. It will NOT accept a bluetooth microphone but will accept the speaker part of the bluetooth headset. I tried to get the microphone to work with Rosetta Stone but no go. Here's the link as proof:
http://support.rosettastone.com/articles/en_US/Text/Will-my-headset-work-with-Rosetta-Stone/?q=Text&l=en_US

Answer (score 0):

You can pair your headset with Os X and just use the microphone. Tested it with my Sennheiser MM400 - though I am not sure if the mic keeps the connection with the mac. When I switched from the input to the output preference pane the mic was „deactivated“. The headset stays paired but it will not send any data. But maybe your application will hold up the connection. I do not have the Rosetta Stone app for testing.